# What are the I, X, Z gates in quantum gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, hadamard

Can someone please explan how the $\rm I$, $\rm X$ and $\rm Z$ gates work?

If $\rm{I = X^2 = Z^2}$, can you explain why this is the case or why it wouldn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by "how do they work"? Can you be more specific? Also, what does their [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix) have anything to do with their ability to "work"?

Answer (score 2):

$I$ is identity operator, which means that input state is not affected. In mathematical notation: $I|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$.

$X$ operator is a negation. It changes 0 to 1 and conversely, i.e. $X|0\rangle = |1\rangle$ and $X|1\rangle = |0\rangle$. If it is applied on a qubit in arbitrary superposition, i.e. $|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$, the state changes to $X|\psi\rangle = \beta|0\rangle + \alpha|1\rangle$.

$Z$ operator is a little bit more difficult to understand for beginners. The operator changes a phase of qubit. Consider for example state $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$. This state is an equally distributed superposition of state $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. When you apply $Z$ operator, you get a state $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)$. This is also an equally distributed superpositon of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, however, the phase changed as you can see from minus sign before $|1\rangle$. If it is applied on a qubit in arbitrary superposition, i.e. $|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$, the state changes to $Z|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle - \beta|1\rangle$. Again, only the phase changes.

An identity $I = X^2 = Z^2$ can be easily verified by direct multiplication of matrix representations of the operators:
$$
X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
Z = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: A small addition: you may also find it intuitive to think of $X^{2} = Z^{2} = I$ like this: if $X$ flips the $|0\rangle$ to the $|1\rangle$ state and vice-versa, then $X^{2} = X*X$ just does the flip twice, which is equal to doing nothing (i.e. $I$ operation). The same reasoning applies to the $Z$ gate.